# Can't access values returned by function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show remaining time till a certain date on a discord bot and have a function to provide the remaining time however the command to call the individual variables says the return variables are not defined.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endTime){
    const total = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    const seconds = Math.floor((total/1000)%60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((total/1000/60)%60);
    const hours = Math.floor((total/(1000*60*60))%24);
    const days = Math.floor(total/(1000*60*60*24));
    return{
        total,
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds
    };
};

if (command == 'time'){
    const releaseDate = 'November 14 2020'
    getTimeRemaining(releaseDate);
    message.channel.send(days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, ' + seconds + ' seconds until ___.');
};
```

What needs to be changed to return the variables with defined values?

Comment: What do you think, what is the effect/purpose of the `return` keyword in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Theory

The problem lie in your understanding of how variables works in programming language. In Javascript and in a lot of other languages as well, there is a notion called [scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). The idea behind scoping is that every variable *(functions too)* are accessible *(ie can be modified or accessed)* only from certain places. These "places" are what we call **scopes**.

The scope of a variable is determined by where your variable have been declared. For example `const seconds = Math.floor((total/1000)%60);` was declared inside `getTimeRemaining` which means that the variable `seconds` will only be known INSIDE `getTimeRemaining` any attempt to access it outside of `getTimeRemaining` will result in an error.

### The Bad Solution

As stated above, a variable is accessible only inside its scope so one way of fixing your problem is to make accessible all the variable you use inside `getTimeRemaining` OUTSIDE of it, in a scope we call the *root scope*, so the process is two folds:

- First we **declare** the variables in the root scope.
- Then we change their values in `getTimeRemaining`.

```js
// use a let instead of const, because we can't modify const after declaration
let total, seconds, minutes, hours, days;


function getTimeRemaining(endTime) {
    // modify the variables of the root scope
    total   = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
    minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    hours   = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    days    = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    // no needs for a return here
};


const releaseDate = 'November 14 2020';
getTimeRemaining(releaseDate);

console.log(days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, ' + seconds + ' seconds until ___.');
```

### The Good Solution

The problem with the solution above is that there is a ton of "optimisation" we can do to make the code more readable, debuggable and upgradable. You see the good thing about scopes is that they allow us to isolate our variables. Lets say that you had a second function named `getTimeBeforeToday` and that function was using also a variable named `seconds`, then you'd get a *side effect* with your variable `seconds` being modified twice by two different functions, which is really bad practice.

The best possible solution is to avoid using global variable *(ie variables declared in the root scope)* and `return` the processed value without exposing the inner variables:

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endTime){

    // these variables are only accessible from inside getTimeRemaining
    const total   = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours   = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const days    = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    // return an object containing only the data we need to expose
    return {
        total,
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds
    };
};

const releaseDate = 'November 14 2020'
// use the returned data
const remainingTime = getTimeRemaining(releaseDate);
console.log(remainingTime.days + ' days, ' + remainingTime.hours + ' hours, ' + remainingTime.minutes + ' minutes, ' + remainingTime.seconds + ' seconds until ___.');
```

Comment: Thank you show much, I understand the concept of scoping now.

Comment: Glad to help @AbdulBasitKhan!

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Your mistake was understandable though. When you called your "getTimeRemaining" function, the returned values are not actually global. You need to get each returned value by actually calling the function (with your returned value using dot notation).

Example code below with comments added.

More on return values here -------> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values

Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTimeRemaining(endTime){
        const total = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        const seconds = Math.floor((total/1000)%60);
        const minutes = Math.floor((total/1000/60)%60);
        const hours = Math.floor((total/(1000*60*60))%24);
        const days = Math.floor(total/(1000*60*60*24));
        return{
            total,
            days,
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds
        };
    };

    const command = 'time'
    


    if (command == 'time'){
        const releaseDate = 'November 14 2020'

        //Just because you ran the function here it doesn't mean those returned values are global
        console.log(getTimeRemaining(releaseDate));

        //You need to actually call the function and pass what you need returned
        console.log(getTimeRemaining(releaseDate).days)

        var total = getTimeRemaining(releaseDate).total,
            days = getTimeRemaining(releaseDate).days,
            hours = getTimeRemaining(releaseDate).hours,
            minutes = getTimeRemaining(releaseDate).minutes,
            seconds = getTimeRemaining(releaseDate).seconds;

        console.log(total, days, hours, minutes, seconds);


        // message.channel.send(days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, ' + seconds + ' seconds until ___.');
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getTimeRemaining(endTime){
  const total = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  const seconds = Math.floor((total/1000)%60);
  const minutes = Math.floor((total/1000/60)%60);
  const hours = Math.floor((total/(1000*60*60))%24);
  const days = Math.floor(total/(1000*60*60*24));
  return {
      total,
      days,
      hours,
      minutes,
      seconds
  };
};

if(command == 'time'){
  const releaseDate = 'November 14 2020'
  let timeRemaining = getTimeRemaining(releaseDate);
  message.channel.send(timeRemaining.days + ' days, ' + timeRemaining.hours + ' hours, ' + timeRemaining.minutes + ' minutes, ' + timeRemaining.seconds + ' seconds until ___.');
};
```

What I'm doing here is creating a new variable called `timeRemaining`. This called your function and in your function you're already returning an object. Once you have a variable that has a value of an object, you can just do . 
ie timeRemaining.day would return the day.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Besides providing a fixed code as an anwer, it's helpful to explain it to the OP what was wrong in their original code so they can learn from the mistake.