# How to display users identity using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need to display users public name via reactjs as per  **{publicName}
OR   {pubname}**
but it throws error, **publicName is not defined**

Here is my Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";

const fetchAccountId = async () => {
  const publicName = "Nancy Moore";
  return publicName;
};

function App() {
  const [accounts] = useState(fetchAccountId);
  fetchAccountId();

  const [pubname, setPubname] = useState(null);
  setPubname(publicName);

  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Display Public Name</h2>

      <div>
        {publicName}
        OR {pubname}{" "}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There is no `publicName` defined in its scope and you shouldn't set state directly as `setPubname(publicName)` It will create infinite loop.

Comment: @DecPK Please how do I do that. Am new this react functional approach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access values returned by function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62854688/cant-access-values-returned-by-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no such `publicName` defined in the `scope` and thus error.

There are following issues in your code snippet:

1. You have to have `publicName` defined in the scope to access it.
2. You shouldn't be setting state in the code directly in components. It will cause infinite renders.
   Better to use `useEffect` and set state in it. So that it will set state only if it is required.

---

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAccountId().then((publicName) => setPubname(publicName));
  }, []);
```

You can also use `async-await` if you prefer to use it:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const publicName = await fetchAccountId()
      setPubname(publicName);
    })();
  }, []);
```

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-pine-rmcg5s?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A0-497)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";

const fetchAccountId = async () => {
  const publicName = "Nancy Moore";
  return publicName;
};

function App() {
  const [accounts] = useState(fetchAccountId);

  const [pubname, setPubname] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAccountId().then((publicName) => setPubname(publicName));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Display Public Name</h2>

      <div>{pubname}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need on adjustment, add change

```
fetchAccountId();
```

with

```
const publicName = fetchAccountId();
```

and it would be better if you use it in `useEffect()`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const publicName = fetchAccountId();
  setPubname(publicName);
}, []);
```

This use effect function will trigger when component is loaded.

Note: the `const publicName` in `fetchAccountId()` is not a global variable it only exists within the `fetchAccountId()` function.